# What is it called when you place text over an image?

Tags: layers, terminology, typesetting, fine-arts

For example, in this album cover:

[image]

Is the text "imposed" over the image?  What is the right word for placing one layer of design on top of another?

Comment: I think you call it 'placing text over an image'

Comment: to **superimpose** text/type **on** an image – see dictionary: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/superimpose?q=superimpose

Comment: TehMacDawg, that is the word I was looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is **overlay text**. Text that covers the surface of the image is called overlay text. Because you can't see the parts of the image that are behind the white stroke of this font I would call it overlay :)

Answer (score 0):

Text over an image.

Text on a background.

As Jenna answered, "overlay text" perhaps - not a term I'd use, but I'd have an *idea* about what someone meant if I heard it. "Overlay" to me, always infers opacity to a degree. Not the same thing in my mind as "text over an image".

I don't think there's a "special" term for it.

Comment: I know what you mean Scott, that's why my answer is so awkwardly worded :) Usually with overlay I would think of layers of video with differing opacity. But then the literal meaning of overlay is to 'cover the surface of' which is why I came to the conclusion that I did. It's not ideal but I think it works,I definitely wouldn't be opposed if we managed to find something a little less confusing :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the word you are looking for is “**compositing**: combine two or more images to make a single picture.” Your example is a composite of an image of text and an image of artwork.